# Javascript Adding Incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML

**HTML**

```
<h1 id="total"></h1>
<div id="option1" onclick="doMath()">Option 1</div>
<div id="option2" onclick="doMath()">Option 2</div>
```

And the following Javascript
**JS**

```
    var basePrice = 0;
    var optiononePrice = 5;
    var optiontwoPrice = 10;

    function doMath() {
        $("#option1").click(function() {
            basePrice += 5;
        });
        $("#option2").click(function() {
            basePrice += 10;
        });
    };
    $("#total").html(basePrice);
```

When a user clicks a div element, the price should add to the total, but this is what happens:

For example, the user clicks option1. The basePrice will print "5", but when they click option1 again, the basePrice goes from "5" to "15", then from "15" to "30" and goes like that every click.
Same with option2, it starts at "10", then goes from "10" to "30" and so on.

What is happening, how should I fix this?

Comment: You keep on adding listeners on each click, so with each click the function gets called another time. All you have to do is put everything on `doMath` outside, delete `doMath` and delete `onclick=doMath()`.

Comment: Separate doMath into two methods and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code

**HTML**

```
<h1 id="total"></h1>
<div id="option1">Option 1</div>
<div id="option2">Option 2</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var basePrice = 0;
var optiononePrice = 5;
var optiontwoPrice = 10;    

    $("#option1").click(function() {
        basePrice += 5;
    });
    $("#option2").click(function() {
        basePrice += 10;
    });

$("#total").html(basePrice);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I will select this as best answer in 6 mins (when I can)